# How to use Zxing in android

Tags: android, zxing

I am new to Zxing. I am doing barcode conversion using zxing in my android application. Can anyone guide me how to include zxing to android device.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If the zxing barcode scanner is installed in the mobile, its very easy:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
       intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");//for Qr code, its "QR_CODE_MODE" instead of "PRODUCT_MODE"
       intent.putExtra("SAVE_HISTORY", false);//this stops saving ur barcode in barcode scanner app's history
       startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

and in `OnActivityResult`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"); //this is the result
            } else 
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
              // Handle cancel
            }
        }
    }
```

If its not installed: u can put this code in try-catch block and catching the exception, u can do this:

```
Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android");
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,marketUri);
startActivity(marketIntent);
```

So it redirects the app to `android market` and ur app continues running once if the `barcode scanner` is installed.

If u dont want to use the other app in ur app, U have to download zxing library and try using the classes from core.jar file(it is created using apache ant). Follow this tutorial to do that: `https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Getting-Started-Developing`

All Intent options can be found here:

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/Intents.java

Comment: Thank you, this is more informative. i downloaded the code from google. and whenever i compile the built script, i am getting error. can we download the core.jar from net.? or do you have core.jar file.

Comment: core.jar file should be generated on your own.

Comment: coz its its not portable

Comment: u have to use apache ant to generate core.jar

Comment: but its rather difficult to use that

Comment: It will be easy if u ask the user to install the default barcoder app

Comment: just giving an intent gives u the result

Comment: i tried but the core.jar is getting error. i cant able to generate the code.jar using ant. i am new to ant. can you able to generate the jar.

Comment: i downloaded core.jar from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/z/Downloadzxing16corejar.htm. is this applicable to use.??

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/GettingStarted i followed this and created core.jar file succesfully

Comment: If u follow the above method, no need to generate core.jar file. Just u can get the barcode scanned using a simple intent

Comment: i followed the above link. i got core.jar in core file. and i applied into my application.but even iam getting error in android application.

Comment: thats y follow this simple method

Comment: I am still getting error, shows that no activity found.

Comment: i already said about that, u will get error if barcode scanner is not installed in the mobile

Comment: put that code in try catch block

Comment: catch the exception and add the above code under exception as i mentioned in the above answer

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work anymore... I've always use it but now I get the error: "No activity found to handle intent [...]"

Comment: The link can be found here : https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/Intents.java

Answer (score 7):

You need to download the Zing's .Jar file & add in to your application folder. Then you can call classes & methods of it.

Comment: what is the reason for down vote ?

Comment: Zxing integration does not work that way..

Comment: @Siddharth - yes, it does. It's open source and this is a common implementation choice.

Answer (score 2):

**Step by step to setup zxing 3.2.1 in eclipse**

1. Download zxing-master.zip from "https://github.com/zxing/zxing"
2. Unzip zxing-master.zip, Use eclipse to import "android" project in zxing-master
3. Download core-3.2.1.jar from "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/3.2.1/"
4. Create "libs" folder in "android" project and paste cor-3.2.1.jar into the libs folder
5. Click on project: choose "properties" -> "Java Compiler" to change level to 1.7. Then click on "Android" change "Project build target" to android 4.4.2+, because using 1.7 requires compiling with Android 4.4
6. If "CameraConfigurationUtils.java" don't exist in "zxing-master/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/". You can copy it from "zxing-master/android-core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/" and paste to your project.
7. Clean and build project. If your project show error about "switch - case", you should change them to "if - else".
8. Completed. Clean and build project