# How to check contents of History in android?

Tags: java, android, zxing

I am running my own application on "Samsung Y" which launches ZXing when triggers button,I don't know how to see details of barcode scanned.

Please someone help me

Answer (score 1):

when you want to call ZXing you put this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Then you make an `onActivityResult` to capture the result from ZXing

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The actual code result 
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"); 
            // Type of barcode scanned (Barcode, QR, etc.)
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT"); //
    }
}
```

You could also use their [intentIntegrator](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent)

Answer (score 0):

There are many similar questions. Check my answer here: [How to use Zxing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708705/how-to-use-zxing-in-android/8708784#8708784) if u want to save history `intent.putExtra("SAVE_HISTORY",true);` instead of `false`

Comment: how to get all history details is there any method ? @Seshu Vinay