# How to convert QR code to number?

Tags: android

i have created QR-code through this site http://qrcode.kaywa.com/ .i have created QR-code for "1". I want read and convert into number.They provided one url for QR code image.Url is http://qrcode.kaywa.com/img.php?s=8&d=1" alt="qrcode".
how to convert QR code to number using URL.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an app like BeeTagg and scan the picture with it. 
That way you can decipher the image.

Answer (score 1):

Use Zxing to read QRCode. Look into my answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708705/how-to-use-zxing-in-android/8708784#8708784). It gives the output in the form of string. you can convert it to integer if you want.