# Integrating zxing barcode scanner

Tags: android, zxing

I want to integrate the zxing barcode scanner into my app. I have followed the steps described here http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/ . But the imported project won't build I receive errors that i should remove the @Override anottation and when I removed it says i should override. So is pretty confusing.The library project has these errors and i don't understand why because i followed the steps just as described in tutorial.

Comment: look into my answer in [this][1]. Its easier way. It may help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708705/how-to-use-zxing-in-android/8708784#8708784

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have different JAVA compiler. May be 1.5 or 1.7

Zxing uses 1.6 Java compiler.

try this

1. Right click on project
2. Properties > Java Compiler > Enable Project specific Settings (Check it)
3. In front of "compiler compliances level" chose 1.6
4. Clean the project
5. and run again

Answer (score 0):

You can download the [ZXing Barcode code Scanner](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list) code from here.

Navigate to **android** folder for Android **Zxing Scanner source**.. After you import the Android Project , some Class file will be shows as missing you will get if you navigate to

```
core ->src->com->google->Zxing
```