# How can I use the Zxing to scan bar code automatically and fixedly

Tags: android, zxing

I use **Zxing** to scan a bar code in Android

```
        Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.scan);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(AntennaShow.this);
        }
    });
```

When I touch the button,I see a **popup menu**,which has *Zxing* and other *bar-code-scan apps* I installed before
Question:
How can I touch the button then automatically run the Zxing **because** 1,I need to use the Zxing to  retrieve information I scanned 2,that can be troublesome for users to choose *the apt app--Zxing*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708705/how-to-use-zxing-in-android

Comment: thanks,I have watched and it helps a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to use the `IntentIntegrator` class supplied with the project. See http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

It will handle restricting to the Barcode Scanner or Barcode Scanner+ packages by default.

Comment: I have saw the website,and I indeed used the **IntentIntegrator** method

Comment: but I just have done the thing that i can invoke the Barcode Scanner from the website.It is hard for me to automatically use the Barcode Scanner without choosing from my 3 apps about bar-code-scan

Comment: I know that I can use the `checkbox` `next time use Barcode Scanner by default`.but if i don't want to do that,how can I do?

Comment: The IntentIntegrator already restricts to just Barcode Scanner. If you use it, it really should not show other apps. It would, if those other apps had declared that *they* are also in the BS package. This is why we really discourage people from copying our app! in that case, not much you can do.

Comment: oh,I see.It seems that the other 2 apps are using the core of your app.Feel honor to talk with the author.Best wishes!

Comment: Feel free to ask those authors to stop intercepting calls meant for Barcode Scanner. It's unethical even.