# Trying to use Zxing QR code reader API results in force close

Tags: java, android

I have integrated the Zxing API and use this code:

```
Intent data = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
```

And getting the result with this code:

```
String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
String format = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
```

But when I run this code, the app will ask to force close.

Comment: You need to post the error log, from the log cat.

Answer (score 1):

When [sending an Intent to startActivity()](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ExampleSend), you must always check if the user has *any* apps that can handle the intent:

> Caution: It's possible that a user won't have any apps that handle the implicit intent you send to [`startActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)). If that happens, the call will fail and your app will crash. To verify that an activity will receive the intent, call [`resolveActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#resolveActivity(android.content.pm.PackageManager)) on your Intent object. If the result is non-null, then there is at least one app that can handle the intent and it's safe to call `startActivity()`. If the result is null, you should not use the intent and, if possible, you should disable the feature that issues the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708705/how-to-use-zxing-in-android/8708784#8708784). App is crashing because Zxing app is not installed in the mobile. I gave a detailed answer in the same link.