# How to get version of qrcode by Zxing Library

Tags: qr-code, zxing

QRCode have many different version (Version 1 (21×21), Version 2 (25×25), ... etc).

I use zxing library to decode qrcode with different versions, and it works fine!

But I don't know how to get the version of qrcode by zxing library in Language (C++)

PS: I tried class *BitMatrixParser* to acieve it, but get Error Msg. "**Could not decode format information**", and don't know what happend?

Comment: **Step by step to setup zxing 3.2.1 in eclipse** Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708705/how-to-use-zxing-in-android/33536249#33536249

Answer (score 1):

In general, not all images will decode. Do you have a specific image that didn't decode? If so, post it. If it's a stream of images, don't expect them all to decode.

I don't think the C++ port returns the qrcode version. Not sure if the Java port does. Feel free to submit a feature issue to the zxing project but it's volunteer, so YMMV.

Comment: I've read from a github post patch proposal that version information can be computed from error correction level and raw bytes. I don't see how, but it only mentioned it.