# How to use the Zxing library class into my application's own package

Tags: android, zxing

I copied the zxing jar file into lib folder of my android app and build the path,but for         some reason I have to use some of the zxing classes into my own package(not the com.google.zxing package). If I tried to put those classes, I used to get the error. But when I import the zxing packages outside my package, I have to change the R.ids of all the zxing classes into my-package.R.id.

So is there any way that I can use zxing classes in my own package?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  If you have imported the library successfully, you should be able to reference those classes using their xzing package names.

Comment: Hi sean and Booger, I downloaded the jar file from here:http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/2.2/   and included that jar into lib folder and right clicked on the project to build path and added that jar file. But eventhough when i use import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat; in my package, it says "The import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat cannot be resolved"....pls help me out.....

Comment: Hi, pls reply to the above comment guys

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with having to install the ZXing app in your device you could scan barcodes via intent as described in [How to use Zxing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708705/how-to-use-zxing-in-android).