# Android ZXing code scanning

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I have implemented code scanning in my android app using ZXing library.
It is working good, I can read codes, read data from them etc.
However there is one issue, when reading code from my monitor, I have to get my phone far away from the code to make it work, here comes my question, is it possible to change this somehow or it is not possible?

Comment: Devices with auto-focus work better. Also try reducing the number of formats you want to scan.

Comment: Reference link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708705/how-to-use-zxing-in-android/33536249#33536249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is how the library behaves. To get better result avg distance you need 2.5cm between your scanning device and barcode.

Comment: Thank you for response, however I think it is way more than 2.5cm